# 'She looked incredible. Then she looked at me'

Tags: transitive-verbs, literary-techniques, rhetorical-devices, intransitive-verbs

Am I correct in saying that the verb 'looked' is intransitive in the first phrase, transitive in the second phrase? Is there a name for this type of rhetorical technique playing on the two senses of the verb 'to look'?

Comment: It’s called ***syllepsis***  but I’m pretty sure this is a duplicate question.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be a syllepsis if there is no word missing? (Syllepsis: 'a form of ellipsis, and like ellipsis the sense of the word is repeated, but not the word itself.')

Comment: not sure where you found that def?!  https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/syllepsis

Comment: _Look_ is a [sense verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), and they are mostly intransitive. The first one is a "flip" verb, with the source of the sensation as subject and the perceiver presupposed (to be _me_). The second one is a volitional agent verb, with the agent/perceiver as subject. _At me_ is a prepositional phrase, not an object. Though if your theory permits, you can reanalyze the sequence _look at_ as a transitive verb (like _listen to_, another sense verb).  The transitive agentive non-volitional sense verb that corresponds to these two senses of _look_ is _see_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using verbs with multiple meanings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34250/using-verbs-with-multiple-meanings)

Comment: Note that the second use is not transitive, but rather the verb is modified by a adverbial prepositional phrase.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I'm still not sure how it can be a syllepsis if the word is repeated, as this definition https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/syllepsis also refers to 'A word modifying two' (the verb never being repeated as in my example.)

Comment: 'She looked incredible and at me' is an example of syllepsis (one word pressed into two different, conflicting roles in the same sentence)  and arguably unacceptable except for comic effect. Your example, with the repeated verb in different sentences (albeit in different roles), is grammatically less contentious (though the first 'looked' is stative, and so the 'then' is suspect).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is an example of **antanaclasis**:

> *antanaclasis*:
>
> The repetition of a word whose meaning changes in the second instance.

[[Rhetoric.byu.edu_Figures of Repetition](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/of%20Repetition.htm#words)]

John Lawler's analysis (in his comment) can hardly be improved upon, but flip verbs have been covered on several occasions.