# What's the term for this grammatical problem? "John has gone home and a hat"

Tags: grammar, terminology, errors

What is the term for the grammatical error where the same word is used to tie together two phrases, but in conflicting ways?

For example:
"John has gone home and a hat" - "John has gone home" works, and "John has a hat" works, but the combination doesn't. "has" is doing double duty and failing at it.

Or:
"The man walks in with a smug look, confident walk and talking animatedly". Again "The man walks in with a smug look" works, and so does "the man walks in talking animatedly", but combining the two with "and" feels awkward at the very least.

Comment: You're mixing up two meanings of has there, and it doesn't make sense. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34254/2303) or [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/23603/2303). Either way, you're probably looking for *zeugma* or *syllepsis*.

Comment: The result of syllepsis per @Robusto is a garden path sentence: You point us to the right, then you go left, and we go "Huh?"

Comment: The second example uses false parallelism. 'He walks in with A, B and C' is required, where A, B and C are all noun phrases, or 'The man walks in with a smug look and a confident walk, the while talking animatedly.'

Comment: @Robusto — *has* the auxiliary verb in *has gone* has no semantic meaning, so I wouldn’t say that *has* has two different meanings here.

Comment: You can’t extract *the man walks in talking animatedly* from your sentence. You *can* extract *\*the man walks in with talking animatedly* (which is clearly incorrect).

Comment: @TinfoilHat No, because the first verb there is actually *has gone*, not *has*. A valid syllepsis there would be "The man has gone home and crazy."

Comment: @Robusto — Yes, that’s why I'm saying the duplicate (Using verbs with multiple meanings) is not relevant to the structure offered by the OP — there’s no *has*/*has* at play.